# How to add video element and make it autoplay with sound enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I put a video tag with autoplay and loop attributes but if i leave this settings the video doesn't autoplay, instead, if i add muted attribute it starts automatically but with audio disabled.
I want to retrieve the video to play auto and with sound.
How can i get this? Maybe jquery ?

Here the code:

```
<video controls autoplay loop>
    <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I tried with muted, it starts auto but without sound

Comment: Can you post some of your code. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide your code and what have you tried so far

Comment: I added code above. I would learn if there is a way to do it just with html

Answer (score 0):

There is a google policy update from 2017 that explains how to add a loop autoplay video and “Muted autoplay is always allowed”, therefore if you want a `loop` `autoplay` video you must include `muted`. Then the user decides to add or not sound with the `controls`.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

```
<video controls autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score -2):

this answer is Based on what I understand from your question.

Here is a simple video auto play with sound that loops.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The video tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[credit](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_loop)

Comment: With this i have already tried: It doesn't start automatically on load

Comment: One detail. It make this behaviour on Google Chrome. On Firefox works perfectly

Comment: @lisarko8077 It works for me in chrome as well as firefox as well as in jsfiddle try clearing your browsers cache.